# Android package names: com.company.... or il.co.company

Tags: android, eclipse, naming-conventions

I know that the standard convention for package names in Android is com.companyname.project .... etc
I was wondering if it makes sense to use il.co instead for a company based in Israel, especially since I have a website that with .co.il and there is a .com out there for someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package naming convention exists primarily to avoid naming clashes (with a few positive side-effects).

So if you control the DNS name `companyname.co.il` but **not** `companyname.com`, then the safe bet is to use `il.co.companyname`. Othrewise your names *might* clash with those of whoever owns `companyname.com`.

If that other owner is unlikely to produce software (or produces software that's unlikely to be used in the same field as yours), you could risk using `com.companyname`, but that brings us to another side effect:

People assume that refersing the domain-part of a package often leads to the producers homepage. So if you call it`com.companyname` and `companyname.com` doesn't actually point to your homepage, then that might confuse.

My suggestion: use `il.co.companyname`.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a case of your taste. Users don't pay attention to your package name. The only important thing here is your code. If in your company it is ok to name packages in such way, then all is going right and you can use such package name.